# Basic C# R-E-P-L

Tags: c#, console, event-handling

So I was thinking of making a C# REPL, as I didn't find any viable solution that would work for me, so I made a simple, basic one, I am sure it can be improved, as it seems once the REPL class is initialized it's hard to add an event handler to it, or access the logs, so I am looking for a way to improve it, here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CS_REPL
{
    public class REPL
    {
        List<string> inputLog;

        public delegate void InputReceived(string input);
        public event InputReceived InputHandler;

        private bool loopEnabled = true;

        public REPL(InputReceived handler)
        {
            inputLog = new List<string>();
            InputHandler += handler;
            while (loopEnabled)
            {
                string input = ReadLine();
                inputLog.Add(input);
                InputHandler?.Invoke(input);
            }
        }

        public string ReadLine()
        {
            PrintShellIndicator();
            return ReadInput();
        }

        public void PrintShellIndicator()
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
        }

        public string ReadInput()
        {
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void setRunning(bool flag)
        {
            loopEnabled = flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> once the REPL class is initialized

You cannot *initialize* or rather create an instance of `REPL` becasue there is an infinite loop in the constructor - the by default you set `loopEnabled = true;`. Is this intended?

> it's hard to add an event handler to it

It's hard because there is no object to work with as the `new REPL(...)` will never return so you can only add the `handler` once via the constructor.

**Code**

The delegate shouldn't be nested inside the `REPL` class. It also shouldn't be a custom delegate too - if used as an `event`. By convention we use the `EventHandler` delegate for this.

As you want to pass the *input* to the event handler you'll need to create custom `EventArgs` to make it possible. There is a generic `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` where you can use the new class.

```
public class InputReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public InputReceivedEventArgs(string input)
    {
        Input = input;
    }

    public string Input { get; }
}
```

The *final* `REPL` class with the new event could look like this:

```
public class REPL
{
    private List<string> _inputLog;

    // Initialize with an empty event handler.
    public event EventHandler<InputReceivedEventArgs> InputReceived = delegate { };

    public REPL()
    {
        _inputLog = new List<string>();
    }

    // Starts the REPL
    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string input = ReadLine();
            _inputLog.Add(input);
            OnInput(input);
        }
    }

    // --- all other methods should be private

    private string ReadLine()
    {
        PrintShellIndicator();
        return ReadInput();
    }

    private void PrintShellIndicator()
    {
        Console.Write("> ");
    }

    private string ReadInput()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Invokes the InputReceived event
    private void OnInput(string input)
    {
        InputReceived.Invoke(this, new InputReceivedEventArgs(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you initialize InputReceived with an empty handler?

Comment: @HenrikHansen to avoid the null-check.

Comment: But isn't the InputReceived?.Invoke() optimized for that or what is most expensive?

Comment: @HenrikHansen there are various opinions, I like the empty handler, see [Is it a good practice to define an empty delegate body for a event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303343/is-it-a-good-practice-to-define-an-empty-delegate-body-for-a-event)

Comment: OK, it's a matter of taste - I don't like that taste ;-)

Comment: I agree with the main point of this answer, but I don't see any reason to use that old `EventHandler`/`EventArgs` style. Using a custom, well-named delegate like in the original question, or even just `Action<string>` seems much better.

Comment: @BenAaronson either one would be fine but the OP mixed both approaches and this definitelly isn't a good solution. As the OP explicitly set the event-handlig tag I assumed he is interested in event handling.

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm talking about using events. E.g. `public event Action<string> OnInput;` (or however you'd name it). I don't see any reason to come up with a `InputReceivedEventArgs` class and send a useless `sender` object

Comment: @BenAaronson this is not how events are supposed to work: _In the .NET Framework class library, events are based on the EventHandler delegate and the EventArgs base class._ see: [Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) _Everyone_ expects an `event` it to be an `EventHandler`

Comment: and this: _The .NET Framework provides the EventHandler and EventHandler<TEventArgs> delegates to support most event scenarios. Use the EventHandler delegate for all events that do not include event data. Use the EventHandler<TEventArgs> delegate for events that include data about the event. These delegates have no return type value and take two parameters (an object for the source of the event and an object for event data)._ [Handling and Raising Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @t3chb0t Well, I don't think the OP is writing for the .NET Framework class, so the first one doesn't seem too relevant. For the second, this is the advice, but it dates back a long time and is mainly relevant for winforms, etc.  Msdn have their own examples recommending deviating from the pattern where appropriate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx

Comment: I do understand the value of following established language conventions, but I also think there's a strong argument that this one is outdated enough, and adds enough pointless fluff to a codebase, that it can be ignored. It'd be interesting to see a survey of modern libraries that use events to see how many stick to the convention and how many don't

Comment: @BenAaronson hehe, but your example supports what I'm saying about events not you ;-) they create a custom delegate - that's true - but they stick to the convention that its signature is `T sender, U eventArgs` - you however wanted to do it with a simple `Action<T>` which is not a _real_ event. Sure, theoretically `Action<TSender, TEventArgs>` would too ;-) it's just a delegate. What I meant was that it should take two parameters. Maybe it's a stupid convention but this is how events _should_ be implemented to be _true_ events. Event the WPF does it this way.